# How to get hostname in freemarker template?

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

I have SpringMVC project with Freemarker as view resolver. In some templates I have to generate links including hostname, but I can't get it.
In JSP I may to do like this:

```
`<% String hostName=request.getServerName();%>`
```

I tried to use "`requestContextAttribute`", but `requestContext.getContextPath()` returned path without hostname. 
Where can I get full path or hostname separately?

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in JSTL. Try adapting it in FreeMarker:

```
${pageContext.request.serverName}
```

Comment: Freemarker don't have pageContext, however I have Request object. How can I get hostname from it?

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand that Freemarker is intentionally designed to not have knowledge of the context in which it's used, to make it more generic. That means that unlike JSPs, it has no access to the HttpServletRequest and Response objects by default.  If you want it to have access, you'll need to provide it.

The way I solved this was to create a Servlet Filter to add the HttpServletRequest object as a Request Attribute which Freemarker does have access to.

```
/**
 * This simple filter adds the HttpServletRequest object to the Request Attributes with the key "RequestObject" 
 * so that it can be referenced from Freemarker.
 */
public class RequestObjectAttributeFilter implements Filter
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    public void init(FilterConfig paramFilterConfig) throws ServletException
    {

    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req,
        ServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        req.setAttribute("RequestObject", req);

        filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void destroy()
    {

    }

}
```

You'll need to define this in your web.xml in order for it to work:

```
<filter>
     <filter-name>RequestObjectAttributeFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>com.foo.filter.RequestObjectAttributeFilter</filter-class>    
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>RequestObjectAttributeFilter</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Then, in my .ftl files, I can use the following:

```
${Request.RequestObject.getServerName()}
```

Comment: You could also add the Request object as an attribute from inside one of your Controllers.  If you don't need this in many places in your site, that's probably better.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work in freemarker:

```
<#assign hostname = request.getServerName() />
<a href="http://${hostname}/foo">bar</a>
```

But with freemarker it's better to get server name in java and push it into template as string.